# Passing a variable as prop to child component

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component which calls for a child component, and I want to pass a variable to the child component. I am able to pass string, but was not able to pass the variable or atleast it's desired value.

My parent component fetches some rows from db. The fetched data is displayed in table and there is a checkbox which upon true gives value to the variable that I want to pass. May be I didn't get the syntax right or something, but I could not read the variable's value in my child component.

//parent component (is already a child of another component)

```
const SalesTable = () => {
//fetched data
let rowIdToSend = [] //declared in top level

 const handleSingleRowSelection =  (event, id) =>{
    if (event.target.checked) {
      rowIdToSend= [] // clearing previous selected row value
      rowIdToSend= id;

      console.log("selected rows", rowIdToSend); //I get row value upon check in checkbox
      return
    }
    selectedRows = []
    console.log("selected rows", rowIdToSend); // Value gets removed upon uncheck
  }

return(
<Child
rowsToModify={{ greeting: rowIdToSend }}
/>
)
}
```

//child component (is just a set of two buttons, update and delete rendered in each row of the fetched data)

```
 const Child= ({rowsToModify}) => {
      const unknnown = rowsToModify
    
      const displaymylog = () => {
        console.log('received');
        console.log(unknnown.greeting);
      };
    
      return (
        <div className="buttonGroup">
          <button onClick={displaymylog}>Update</button>
          <button>Delete</button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default Child
```

Comment: create a setState and set the value to it on selection pass the setState's state value to the child it will work

Comment: cant we do it with variable?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with the variable? For passing around probably no, it won;'t trigger any update  unless its a hook state. The reason for that is react needs to know when to rebuild the ui and can't do that automatically on every variable change, it would be too inefficient

Answer (score 0):

You need to use state to manage values

```
const [rowIdToSend, setRowIdToSend] = useState([]);
```

you should change in code like:

```
const handleSingleRowSelection = (event, id) => {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      setRowIdToSend([id]); // Set selected row ID as array
    } else {
      setRowIdToSend([]); // Clear selected row
    }
  };
```

Comment: is it not possible with variable? just to avoid going with variable in future if it is not possible.

Comment: While you can use variables in your components, they won't automatically trigger re-renders when their values change, and this can lead to unexpected behavior in your application.